# Searching for a Python lightweight IDE (or text-editor)

Tags: python, ide, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Hi all,

I'm looking for either a lightweight IDE or a text-editor (with plugins, of course) for writing Python code. Some of the features I'd like the software to provide are as follows:

1) Auto-complete/suggest
2) Multi-tab
3) Auto-format (on save if it is possible)
4) Syntax highlighting
5) Easy navigation between .py code (in Eclipse, if you use F3, you can jump to the Class/Interface file)
6) Expand/Collapse (more known as Folding?)
7) Integrate with code-checking specific to Python (code analysis, unit-test tools, etc)
8) [Optional] Source tree (browsing/navigation)

I prefer to use keyboard to navigate around because I'm using a laptop (with limited display size as well) and I'd like to avoid using mouse.

Update: Please list the plugin names as well if the out-of-the-box doesn't provide them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You mention Eclipse - what about [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), a Python IDE for Eclipse?

edit - also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) has an incredibly comprehensive list of Python IDEs, sorted by feature. Might be worth a look.

Comment: I believe Eclipse doesn't comply with the question main requirement: A "lightweight" editor

Comment: With regards to nowadays personal computer's performance, pydev for Eclipse is a good option.
Just follow the instructions here to download Eclipse, and install pydev. http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

Answer (score 1):

[Wingware](http://www.wingware.com/)'s Python IDE fulfills all of your requirements, and I do consider it to be the best Python IDE around. That being said, it's a commercial product and not available free of charge, though Wingware offers noncommercial/open-source licensing.

Comment: Well there's a workaround to that if you're an active open source project, but it's a bit difficult to get approved for it

Comment: Yep, I just remembered that, too and edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

There is python.el (written by Emacs community) and python-mode.el (written by Python community) for Emacs.  Also, rope, ropemacs, and a few more.  Look at [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org), you will find something for sure if you are open to use Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, I would suggest you give [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/). Might not be lightweight, but it sure is nice.

Cruder look, but very lightweight and extremely powerful: you could look at using [Vim as a Python IDE](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/).

Comment: Looks to me like all of the requirements can be matched by Vim, not out of the box though. Still Vim is worth the effort since it pays off manyfold.